# Removing track from a users favorite list

Tags: soundcloud

I'm using soundcloud's PHP sdk. I want to remove a track from my favorites by using the users subresource listed here: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users.

I'm trying the following but it gives me a 404:

```
$soundcloud->delete('me/favorites/'.$track_id);
```

Comment: the endpoint is "/me/[...]"

Comment: Doens't make a difference. I've been using $soundcloud->get('me/favorites') anyways. This does work.